# why does not readelf report right sizes?

Tags: elf

I have a Linux executable file (which is an ELF file) called `a.out`.

I use

```
readelf -hl a.out
```

and get output

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - GNU
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x4008e0
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          910680 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         6
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         33
  Section header string table index: 30

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                 0x00000000000c9be6 0x00000000000c9be6  R E    200000
  LOAD           0x00000000000c9eb8 0x00000000006c9eb8 0x00000000006c9eb8
                 0x0000000000001c98 0x0000000000003550  RW     200000
  NOTE           0x0000000000000190 0x0000000000400190 0x0000000000400190
                 0x0000000000000044 0x0000000000000044  R      4
  TLS            0x00000000000c9eb8 0x00000000006c9eb8 0x00000000006c9eb8
                 0x0000000000000020 0x0000000000000050  R      8
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     10
  GNU_RELRO      0x00000000000c9eb8 0x00000000006c9eb8 0x00000000006c9eb8
                 0x0000000000000148 0x0000000000000148  R      1

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id .rela.plt .init .plt .text __libc_freeres_fn __libc_thread_freeres_fn .fini .rodata __libc_subfreeres __libc_atexit .stapsdt.base __libc_thread_subfreeres .eh_frame .gcc_except_table 
   01     .tdata .init_array .fini_array .jcr .data.rel.ro .got .got.plt .data .bss __libc_freeres_ptrs 
   02     .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id 
   03     .tdata .tbss 
   04     
   05     .tdata .init_array .fini_array .jcr .data.rel.ro .got
```

According to the above output, this ELF file should have size

```
ELF header size : 64
  +
Section headers : 64*33 = 2112
  +
Program headers : 56*6 = 336
  +
Segments : 834090 = 0x00000000000c9be6 + 0x0000000000001c98 + 0x0000000000000044 + 0x0000000000000020 + 0x0000000000000148 

= 64 + 2112 + 336 + 834090 = 836602
```

However, `/bin/ls` reports file size 912792.
where are the `912792 - 836602 = 76190` bytes?
which parts did I forget to count?

## UPDATE

according to @Jonathon Reinhart, I re count the size using section sizes instead of segment size by

```
echo "print 0x020 + 0x024 + 0x0f0 + 0x01a + 0x0a0 + 0x09eda4 + 0x02529 + 0x0de + 0x09 + 0x01d320 + 0x050 + 0x08 + 0x01 + 0x08 + 0x0b04c + 0x0b2 + 0x020 + 0x010 + 0x010 + 0x08 + 0x0e4 + 0x010 + 0x068 + 0x01ad0 + 0x023 + 0x0f18 + 0x0169 + 0x0b100 + 0x0685a" | /usr/bin/python
```

The section size values used above are extracted from the output of `readelf -S a.out` and the size of section type of "NOBITS" were not counted.

The above code output `909459` which is bigger than segment size `834090`,
however, the total size is still not equal to the file size.

```
64 + 2112 + 336 + 909459 = 911971 != 912792
```

still missing `912792 - 911971 = 821` bytes.

## update2 [solved]

according to the comment, I have test the offset. The result tells me that the adding pad does exist.

Comment: There are often sections which are not loaded, and therefore not included in the segments (not referenced by a program header)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I have counted section size instead of counting segments. However, we still missing some bytes.

Comment: If you check out the offsets and sizes in the section headers, I think you'll notice some gaps, necessary in order to ensure alignment of those sections that need it.